# D3 Redraw Chart Interval

Tags: php, ajax, d3.js

I have a D3 Radar Chart with the current setup so far. A 'phpmysqlconnect.php' file/include which does a PDO SQL query. AJAX fetchdata with an interval which seems to work and show with console log. I am now trying/wanting to get the Radar Chart to redraw with every time there is a change to data or set to a fixed time interval.

Anyway to do this?

home.php

```
<?php include 'phpmysqlconnect.php' ?>

<script>
    function fetchdata(){
     $.ajax({
      url: 'phpmysqlconnect.php',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(data){

       // Set result to div or target 
            $('#my-result').html(data); 
      }
     });
    }
    // interval fetch
    $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(fetchdata,5000);
    });
</script>

<!-- show results -->
<div id="my-result"></div>

<div class="radarChart"></div>
<script src="radarChart.js"></script>

<script>

/* Radar chart design created by Nadieh Bremer - VisualCinnamon.com */

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    //////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
        width = Math.min(700, window.innerWidth - 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = Math.min(width, window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////// Data ////////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


    var data = [
              [
                {axis:"Battery Life",value:<?php echo json_encode($data[0]['field_18']) ?>},
                {axis:"Brand",value:<?php echo json_encode($data[0]['field_19']) ?>},
                {axis:"Contract Cost",value:<?php echo json_encode($data[0]['field_20']) ?>},
                {axis:"Design And Quality",value:<?php echo json_encode($data[0]['field_21']) ?>},
                {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value:<?php echo json_encode($data[0]['field_22']) ?>},
                {axis:"Large Screen",value:<?php echo json_encode($data[0]['field_23']) ?>},
                {axis:"Price Of Device",value:1},
                {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value:2}
              ]
            ];

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    //////////////////// Draw the Chart ////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#EDC951","#CC333F","#00A0B0"]);

    var radarChartOptions = {
      w: width,
      h: height,
      margin: margin,
      maxValue: 5,
      levels: 5,
      roundStrokes: false,
      color: color
    };
    //Call function to draw the Radar chart
    RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);

</script>
```

phpmysqlconnect.php

```
<?php
  require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    try {
        //PDO is a extension which  defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP.
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // prepare the sql query
        $sql = 'SELECT cast(avg(field_18) as unsigned) AS field_18, cast(avg(field_19) as unsigned) AS field_19, cast(avg(field_20) as unsigned) AS field_20, cast(avg(field_21) as unsigned) AS field_21, cast(avg(field_22) as unsigned) AS field_22, cast(avg(field_23) as unsigned) AS field_23 FROM rstutdmkgk.craft_freeform_submissions WHERE formId =1';
        $row = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        //execute the query
        $row->execute();
        //create the array 
        $data=array();  
            //foreach loop
            foreach($row as $rec)  
            {
                    $json_array['field_18']=$rec['field_18']; 
                    $json_array['field_19']=$rec['field_19'];
                    $json_array['field_20']=$rec['field_20']; 
                    $json_array['field_21']=$rec['field_21'];
                    $json_array['field_22']=$rec['field_22'];
                    $json_array['field_23']=$rec['field_23'];
                    //here pushing the values in to an array  
                    array_push($data,$json_array);
            }
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
    }
?>

<script>
  // Echo the data directly to JavaScript
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
  // console log
  console.log('<?php echo json_encode($data[0]['field_18']) ?>')
  console.log(data[0]['field_18']); // field 18
  console.log(data[0]['field_19']); // field 19
  console.log(data[0]['field_20']); // field 20
  console.log(data[0]['field_21']); // field 21
  console.log(data[0]['field_22']); // field 22
  console.log(data[0]['field_23']); // field 23
</script>
```

Edit home.php

```
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#EDC951","#CC333F","#00A0B0"]);

    var radarChartOptions = {
      w: width,
      h: height,
      margin: margin,
      maxValue: 5,
      levels: 5,
      roundStrokes: false,
      color: color
    };
    //Call function to draw the Radar chart
    radarChart = RadarChart("#radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);

     d3.select("#radarChart")
       .call(radarChart);

     radarChart.options(radarChartOptions).update();
```

console for home.php

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Array._a.call (d3.min.js:3)
    at <anonymous>:53:6
    at t.activateScript (rocket-loader.min.js:1)
    at rocket-loader.min.js:1
    at t.run (rocket-loader.min.js:1)
    at rocket-loader.min.js:1
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (rocket-loader.min.js:1)
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://bl.ocks.org/TennisVisuals/c591445c3e6773c6eb6f

Comment: Thanks @delboy1978uk I have tried to make some edits to the call /draw function but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with the same version you are currently working with, but this snippet is doesn't include Ajax call, so check the second snippet to for the Ajax call (Which I'm not sure will work since you didn't include your php code).

```js
/* Radar chart design created by Nadieh Bremer - VisualCinnamon.com */

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
//////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
  width = Math.min(700, window.innerWidth - 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = Math.min(width, window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
////////////////////////// Data ////////////////////////////// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

var data = [
      [//iPhone
      {axis:"Battery Life",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Brand",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Contract Cost",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Design And Quality",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Large Screen",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Price Of Device",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100}   
      ],[//Samsung
      {axis:"Battery Life",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Brand",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Contract Cost",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Design And Quality",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Large Screen",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Price Of Device",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100}
      ],[//Nokia Smartphone
      {axis:"Battery Life",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Brand",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Contract Cost",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Design And Quality",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Large Screen",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Price Of Device",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100}
      ]
    ];
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
//////////////////// Draw the Chart ////////////////////////// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#EDC951","#CC333F","#00A0B0"]);

var radarChartOptions = {
  w: width,
  h: height,
  margin: margin,
  maxValue: 0.5,
  levels: 5,
  roundStrokes: true,
  color: color
};
//Call function to draw the Radar chart
RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);

setInterval(function() {
  var data = [
      [//iPhone
      {axis:"Battery Life",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Brand",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Contract Cost",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Design And Quality",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Large Screen",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Price Of Device",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100}   
      ],[//Samsung
      {axis:"Battery Life",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Brand",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Contract Cost",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Design And Quality",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Large Screen",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Price Of Device",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100}
      ],[//Nokia Smartphone
      {axis:"Battery Life",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Brand",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Contract Cost",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Design And Quality",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Large Screen",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"Price Of Device",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100},
      {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value: (Math.random() * 100) / 100}
      ]
    ];
    RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);
}, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300;
  fill: #242424;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.legend {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  fill: #333333;
}

.tooltip {
  fill: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nbremer/21746a9668ffdf6d8242/raw/980dda56c87a6813fc4ba527ec7db0b53e83dbb5/radarChart.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/ >
  <title>Smoothed D3.js Radar Chart</title>

  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- D3.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="radarChart"></div>

  <script src="http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/raw/21746a9668ffdf6d8242/980dda56c87a6813fc4ba527ec7db0b53e83dbb5/radarChart.js"></script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Update: here is a working version of the chart with php code, I mocked the data in `phpmysqlconnect.php`, I removed the script definition in `phpmysqlconnect.php` since its not clean to have your data defined in PHP, you can just use `echo json_encode($data);`

**please note that you have to return `Array` of `Array` of `Objects` so that the Library can handle your data**.

**Home.php**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    function fetchdata(){
     $.ajax({
      url: 'phpmysqlconnect.php',
      type: 'get',
      type: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        var radarChartOptions = {
          w: width,
          h: height,
          margin: margin,
          maxValue: 5,
          levels: 5,
          roundStrokes: false,
          color: color
        };
        RadarChart(".radarChart", JSON.parse(data), radarChartOptions);
      }
     });
    }
    // interval fetch
    $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(fetchdata,1000);
    });
</script>

<!-- show results -->
<div id="my-result"></div>

<div class="radarChart"></div>
<script src="radarChart.js"></script>

<script>

/* Radar chart design created by Nadieh Bremer - VisualCinnamon.com */

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    //////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
        width = Math.min(700, window.innerWidth - 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = Math.min(width, window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////// Data ////////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


    var data = [
      [
        {axis:"Battery Life",value: 12},
        {axis:"Brand",value: 30},
        {axis:"Contract Cost",value: 40},
        {axis:"Design And Quality", value: 15},
        {axis:"Have Internet Connectivity",value: 73},
        {axis:"Large Screen",value: 42},
        {axis:"Price Of Device",value: 20},
        {axis:"To Be A Smartphone",value: 29}
      ]
    ];

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    //////////////////// Draw the Chart ////////////////////////// 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#EDC951","#CC333F","#00A0B0"]);

    var radarChartOptions = {
      w: width,
      h: height,
      margin: margin,
      maxValue: 5,
      levels: 5,
      roundStrokes: false,
      color: color
    };
    //Call function to draw the Radar chart
    RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);

</script>
```

**phpmysqlconnect.php**:

```
<?php
  // YOUR SQL CONNECT GOES HERE. 
  // REPLACE $data with PDO/MYSQLI QUERY DATA.
  $data =  [ [
    ( Object )["axis" => "Battery Life","value" => (rand(1, 99))],
    ( Object )["axis" => "Brand","value" => rand(1, 99)],
    ( Object )["axis" => "Contract Cost","value" => rand(1, 99)],
    ( Object )["axis" => "Design And Quality","value" => rand(1, 99)],
    ( Object )["axis" => "Have Internet Connectivity","value" => rand(1, 99)],
    ( Object )["axis" => "Price Of Device","value" => rand(1, 99)],
    ( Object )["axis" => "To Be A Smartphone","value" => rand(1, 99)],
  ] ];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I have just added my "phpmysqlconnect.php" file to my question. I have tried placing the data inside ajax and then again with interval. Chart does now redraw.

Currently I see values change in console log, just not getting the chart to redraw/update

Comment: Ok, I will try to mock the database function, will check it now.

Comment: Thank you. I am also currently looking at the enhanced version of the radar chart and see if I can merge in what I have so far

Comment: @TonyClemmey, I updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to merge this in now. In the array of objects...How do I alter the "( "rand(1, 99)" values to the actual DB field values I had before like "$json_array['field_18']=$rec['field_18'];" which would get whats in the DB field.

Comment: replace `( Object )["axis" => "Battery Life","value" => rand(1, 99)] ` with `( Object )["axis" => "Battery Life","value" => $rec['field_18']]` do so with other fields too.

Comment: @TonyClemmey, sorry for not being able to help, I tried to help as much as possible, I have to go maybe if its not urgent we can check it later!

Comment: That would be great. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Mamounothan I have merged my bits into http://bl.ocks.org/TennisVisuals/c591445c3e6773c6eb6f and stored in a git repo/fork https://github.com/tonyclemmey/updating-radar-chart It is just updating the chart without refresh left to solve. I have demo page up at https://admin.tonyclemmeydesign.co.uk/fbi/updating-radar-chart/demo.php